# Allow different sources for each window w/ dynamic keyboard layout for new windows

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, window

There are two options in Ubuntu Gnome regarding keyboard layouts in different windows:

-Use the same source for all windows

-Allow different sources for each window

Is it possible to use the second option so that changing my keyboard layout doesn't affect layouts in other windows, but set a dynamic default keyboard layout, so that each NEW window I open has the keyboard layout I used in the previous window, as opposed to each new window simply using a predefined default keyboard layout?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: [There's such an option for Linux Mint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyE2H.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While that feature is present with e.g. Unity or MATE, it seems to be missing in the GNOME desktop used by standard Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks! I can see that it's missing though. What I mean is, is there a way to tweak that using a gnome extension, or with dconf-editor or otherwise? Or is it entirely impossible with gnome so far?

Comment: @IgorKobzev: Sorry for stating what you already said in your question. ;) I'm not able to tell whether there is a way. I wouldn't know how, though.